# Date + 14 days. The date is generated by a regular expression

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a speadsheet in which the first column is like

```
Column 1
-------------------------
Foo 1234 (22.09.21)
Baaaar 5678 (20.10.21)
```

And a second column contains dates only and is generated from the first one by the `=REGEX()` function:

```
=REGEX($A2,"^.+\(([[:digit:]|\.]+)\)$","$1")
```

```
Column 2
-------------------------
22.09.21
20.10.21
```

And I need a third column, which should contain values generated as `date_in_column_2 + 14_days`.

What I have I tried is `=B2+14` in C2, but if the date in B2 is generated by a regex instead of typed by hand, `=B2+14` in C2 gives me an error.

How should I fix it? Thanks.

Also, there is another question. I know it is against Q&A rules and I can ask it as a separate question, but in case it is really easy, could one show how to perform `date_in_column_2 + 14_days` calculation for working days only, i.e. without Saturdays and Sundays?

Comment: https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/creating-a-date-column-with-2-weeks-added-to-each-previous-date-cell/17671

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the string result of your regex into a (numeric) date value first before applying calculations on that value.

LibreOffice provides the **[DATEVALUE()](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_datevalue.html)** function to convert the date string, so you need to embed your formula in Column B into that function:

> =DATEVALUE(REGEX($A2,"^.+(([[:digit:]|.]+))$","$1"))

To get the result displayed as date instead of an numeric value, you need to format column 2 appropriately (Date format).

To add 14 working days, LibreOffice provides the **[WORKDAY()](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_workday.html)** function. Thus, put it into Column C with "B2" as first argument and "14" as second one:

> =WORKDAY(B2,14, )

Result:

[image]

BTW, i had to adapt your regex to get it working for me (*LO 7.0, german localization, semicolon as argument separator*) as follows:

> =REGEX($A2;".*(([[:digit:]|.]+))";"$1")

Thus, together with DATEVALUE(), i've used

> =DATEVALUE(REGEX($A2;".*(([[:digit:]|.]+))";"$1"))

Comment: I believe your answer is correct, but for some reason it doesn't work for me, it gives me 502 error. The B2 cell is already in the proper DD.MM.YY date format. Also, it seems the regex in your answer differs from mine: it doesn't use escaping. I tried both version, with and without escaping, still doesn't work.

Comment: But it works if the date in A2 uses slashes instead of dots. And of course, I edit the regex itself to reflect this change. Very strange.

Comment: OK, I figured it out. It was necessary to change the locale: Tools > Options > Language Settings > Languages > Locale setting (why not just "Locale"?) = Russian